# /etc/hosts not blocking anything

Tags: hosts

I am trying to use `/etc/hosts` on my mac to block infamous scumbag sites like `mackeeper.com` and `com-cleaner.systems` from ever loading again in popups.

While doing that I've found these entries on my `hosts` file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1              localhost
```

so I have added these...

```
127.0.0.1  mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1  www.mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1  mackeeperapp.zeobit.com
127.0.0.1  mackeeperapp2.mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1  *.mackeeper.com
127.0.0.1  activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1  practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1  *.com-cleaner.systems
127.0.0.1  *.bet.pt
```

and all these sites continue to load fine even after a restart.

I have tried also adding the same lines with `fe80::1%lo0` and `::1` without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Though this will not answer your question, you could install some pop-up blocker extension plus an ad-blocker.

Comment: Please edit question with contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Wildcards like `*.bet.pt` will not work in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz - brilliant. The problems were the wildcards. Please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

macOS has a DNS cache, and if the IP addresses of the problem sites are already in your DNS cache, editing `/etc/hosts` won't have an immediate effect.

The procedure for flushing the DNS cache is annoyingly version-dependent:

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214981288-Flushing-your-DNS-cache-in-Mac-OS-X-and-Linux

- 10.4: `lookupd -flushcache`
- 10.5, 10.6: `dscacheutil -flushcache`
- 10.7, 10.8: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- 10.9: `dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- 10.10.1 .. 10.10.3: `sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches`
- 10.10.4+: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- 11: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- 12+: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper; sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: Thank you for actually including the solution for people who (like me) haven't upgraded past 10.4!

Comment: I've learned that it's useful to quote the essential parts of a linked solution, in case the linked article goes away someday. This way the answer will also work stand-alone even if the link becomes outdated.